# Can anyone explain the intuition behind this proof that a rational number exists between any two real numbers?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I'm new to proofs and I'm trying to understand how to approach them. I understand the proof itself, I'm just wondering what would prompt someone to come up with it and how I can build up enough mathematical intuition to do the same.

> If $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a < b$, then $\exists x \in \mathbb{Q}$ s.t. $a < x < b$.
>
> Proof:
>
> Since $\mathbb{Z}$ increases without bound, $\exists n \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $\frac{1}{b-a}<n$. Therefore $\frac{1}{n} < b-a$.
>
> Choose $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ as large as possible satisfying $\frac{m}{n} \leq a$.
>
> Then $a < \frac{m+1}{n}$, and also $\frac{m+1}{n}=\frac{m}{n} + \frac{1}{n} < a + (b-a) = b$
>
> $\therefore$ taking $x=\frac{m+1}{n} \in \mathbb{Q}$ satisfies $a < x < b$. $\square$

I understand this is a direct proof of existence by finding an element in the domain of discourse that satisfies the conditional proposition. These are the proofs I seem to have the most trouble with because they involve a "wildcard."

For instance, I get why we picked $\frac{m}{n} = a$ initially. It makes sense to start at the lower bound of the interval. But why did we, all of a sudden, decide to check $\frac{m+1}{n}$. It's not like that's the "next" rational number (because there's no such thing). The choice to examine $\frac{m+1}{n}$ inspired the choice of $n$ and the whole proof just came together. But how, on earth, did the author cook up $\frac{m+1}{n}$. Is there something that would explain his train of thought other than the fact that he's smarter than me?

How would you approach this proof?

Comment: Drawing a picture of all of these numbers helps, in this case. Imagine walking along 1/n, 2/n, 3/n, etc. until you land between a and b (why must it happen that you land between them?)

Comment: It is  the same idea as in "*if $\,b - a \gt 1\,$ then there exists (at least) one integer $\,k\,$ in the interval $\,(a,b)\,$*". To prove that you take the largest integer $\,k \le a\,$ then argue that $\,k+1\,$ cannot possibly be "beyond" $\,b\,$ because $\,b-a\,$ is "too wide" a gap.

Comment: @Matt I don't know. If $a$, and $b$ were natural numbers or integers I'd say because the difference between any two consecutive elements of that sequence is less than 1 (which is the distance between $a$ and $b$). But since they're real numbers, I can't answer that.

Comment: @dxiv I'm sorry, I don't understand the connection. Nothing is given about $a$ and $b$ other than the fact that they are real numbers. How can we think about the distance between two arbitrary real numbers? There is no limit to how small/large it is.

Comment: @alwaysiamcaesar `How can we think about the distance between two arbitrary real numbers?` That's a fixed distance $\,b-a \gt 0\,$ for two given numbers, no matter how small that distance may be. Find a large enough $\,n\,$ such that $\,n(b-a) = nb - na \gt 1\,$, then the problem reduces to the one in my previous comment i.e. find an integer inside $\,(na,nb)\,$.

Comment: The issue is : if $a$ and $b$ are different, there is a distance (big or small) between them. This distance cannot be $0$ (otherwise $a=b$). Thus, we can find something inside : the real nuber line has no "empty spaces".

Comment: Only you picked m/n = a.